Should we always update the [java] version?
From time to time, there are suggested edits like this about the java tag wiki and I agree that these would be an improvement over the previous tag wiki when a new Java version comes out.
However, there are many, most of them coming from a user who seems to want to "maintain" that tag wiki and in my opinion, it seems to be unnecessary work for no significant advantage.
I am not talking about major versions, I do think it makes sense to have major versions and their release dates in there. However, the tag wiki contains the latest minor version corresponding to each major Java version along with the release date of that minor version. To be honest, I don't think anyone cares when a minor version has been released.
Furthermore, it is confusing as the minor version is in parenthesis (indicating it wouldn't be that important) while the date next to it corresponds to the minor version so a person might think that Java 21 has been released on January 16, 2024 (or April 16, 2024 after the given edit) even though that's specific to 21.0.2 (or 21.0.3) because it's written next to Java Standard Edition 21.
So, I propose to

Change the Release Date column of the Latest Stable Versions table of the java tag wiki so that in contains the release dates of the major releases instead of the release dates of the minor releases.
Remove the minor versions in brackets in that table.

I could be convinced to not remove the minor versions if there is significant advantage in keeping those but I definitely think the Release Date column should give information about the release dates of the major versions. Currently, it looks like e.g. Java Standard Edition 17 has been released before Java Standard Edition 18.
If it was a small tag, I would have just suggested an edit to the wiki removing it as tags generally shouldn't contain version information but since it's one of the most used tags, I am asking this here on MSE.

I would completely remove the "Latest Stable Versions" section.
I don't see that the section provides much value with regards to asking and answering questions on Stack Overflow.  Ultimately, this should be the most important metric when it comes to the tag wiki.
On the other hand, having information about the major versions is often useful.  I feel like the "Notable Java versions, code names, and release dates include" section better serves that need than "Latest Stable Versions".  Having both sections is unhelpfully redundant.

Here is my reasoning: this seems like double maintenance to me. The tag description already has a link to the Wikipedia page on Java. It maintains a version history as well. If you really must know (and the situations where you really must know seem very rare to me), it's there.

@Gimby Fair point; I'm not even addressing the maintenance burden in my answer, just the end result on the Q&A site.

As the mentioned person who likes to maintain it, here are my two cents.

There is a Notable Java versions, code names, and release dates include: section which lists the release date of each major release, which handles the proposal of the OP.
As a developer which has a daily test case to check the latest Java version, the Wiki page isn't the reference, so it really doesn't add much value in this regard, at least for my team.

I think it is more about the value of the Latest Stable Versions section, whether it adds a value or not. I am inclined to either keep it as is (with minor versions updated) or to remove the section completely, but other users' opinions would help in deciding this.
If the dates are confusing, we can have two columns, Major version release date and Latest version release dates (or something similar).

Regarding your edit: While this would make it unambiguous, I think this would just make the tag wiki bigger/require more work updating and reviewing for no significant advantage.

I praise your neutrality in this answer!

Upvoted for the "I am inclined to [...] remove the section completely" part.

If you really need to document Java versions in the tag wiki, just link to this Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history.  It has a comprehensive list of versions (and patch releases).

I couldn't agree more. I don't see how the version history in the tag wiki is remotely relevant to posting or answering questions in a tag. Keep the FAQ section and anything else related to SO, dump the rest since it's just derivative or easily Googleable.

I can call this the Stack Overflow effect. Given enough time, people will demonstrate they really cannot contain themselves and will turn valuable information into the worst form of bloatware by endlessly stacking on more and more content. This is true in meta posts, it is true in questions with 500 answers, it is true in tag descriptions. There is a hole in site policy there. The name "stack overflow" is taken a little too literally :/

@Gimby I recall the same being true on Wikipedia when I used to edit there, until someone came along and intentionally pruned things down.  So I suspect this is probably true of pretty much any form of collaborative editable content.

@M.Justin - Yea ... but people bike-shedding the Wikipedia article is not >our< problem to solve :-)
